# SNMP to read tape status on AS/400?

Tags: snmp, ibm-midrange

I have a 3580 on an AS/400 and want to monitor tape status, most importantly, is one actually inserted, using SNMP get.

Find a lot of SNMP details on tape libraries, but for a stand alone drive I assume this would have to come from the OS device status.

Any idea of OID(s) that would be helpful?

EDIT:

Does not look like there is a native OID. Are there any examples of OID extensions using SNMP sub-agents I could look at?

EDIT:

Actually, coding a subagent to extend the IOD tree is a programming function, not an admin function, so probably should be asked elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any OID's to provide the information you are looking for.  It may be possible to implement custom OID's.

The only way I know of to even detect if a tape is inserted is to attempt to access it with `CHKOBJ DEV(TAP01)`, for example, and monitoring for an escape message.

Reference

- [An Introduction to AS/400 SNMP Support](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg244504.html)

Comment: Yes, my research says the same thing. Extending with a sub-agent would be the only way. I'll expand the question; are there any open source examples of SNMP sub-agents running around out there?

Comment: @tlum I know [there's a RedBook for that](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg244504.html) (in fact the one JamesA also linked to :-) I haven't read it in years, but there is a chapter on subagents that might be helpful.